# Series and sequences convergence with a certain condition.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n})$ converge. Let $\{n_{k}\}$ be a subsequence of the sequence of positive integers. For each $k$ define

$b_{k}=a_{n_{k-1}+1}+...+a_{n_{k}}$

where $n_{0}=0$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_{k})$ converge and that :

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_{k})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n})$

I got stuck,and I dont know how to attack this problem, the intuition tell me that what is happening in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_{k})$ is that we choose terms of $a_{n}$ an add terms between them, but I dont know how it is useful, and moreover how to prove this, thank you for your help, I really nedd it

**Attempt
  Then we have in general that**  $b_{1}= a_{1}+...+a_{n_{1}}$...$b_p=a_{n_{p-1}+1}+...+a_{n_{p}}$ **then if we sum every of this terms is clearly that**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p}{b_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n_p}{a_k}$$

**and this means that**

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{p}{b_k}}=\lim_{p\to\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n_p}{a_k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$$

**and since** $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_{k}}$ **converges then** $\sum_{k=1}^{p}{b_k}$ c**onverges and we are done**

**Am I right or what do I have to cahnge here, thanks a lot for your help**

Comment: yes is right, the book has it like that :)

Comment: I will edited is wrong :) thanks

Comment: there is the good one :)

Answer (score 2):

Compare the $p$th partial sum of $\sum{b_k}$ with the $n_p$th partial sum of $\sum{a_k}$. Their difference is $0$ so the first sum converges to the same value as a subsequence of the partial sums of the second sum.

That is, show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p}{b_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n_p}{a_k}$$
which means
$$\lim_{p\to\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{p}{b_k}}=\lim_{p\to\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n_p}{a_k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$$

Comment: Can you post the comparation explicity in your answer please  :), I dont understand you idea to much :) thanks for the help in advance

Comment: See the edit I made above.

Comment: ok thank you, I will do that, and can you help with the verification, today or tommorow when I post my answer plase ?

Comment: If you leave a comment here you can direct me where to look. I may not be able to respond until evening though (EST) because I will be at work during the day.

Comment: Ok excellent I wool do it

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^m b_{k} = \sum_{n=1}^{n_m} a_{n}$

Consider the convergence of the right hand side as $m$ increases

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the problem
is writing
$b_{k}=a_{n_{k-1}+1}+...+a_{n_{k}}
$.
I find it clearer
to write this in the
$\sum$ form as
$b_{k}=\sum_{i=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_{k}} a_i
$.

From this,
it is easier
(to me)
to prove by induction that
$\sum_{k=1}^m b_{k}
=\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{i=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_{k}} a_i
=\sum_{j=1}^{n_m} a_j
$.

Note that
this provides 
a nice generalization 
of the condensation test for
convergence or divergence.

Comment: Can you please post how you do the induction please ?, is interesting, and I think is easier, because with the other method I am getting stuck with the computations of the b_k's,and when we have the equality, then we are done isnt?

Comment: You need a theorem of the form if $a, b, c$ are integers such that $a \le b \le c$ then $\sum_{n=a}^{b-1} v_n + \sum_{n=b}^{c-1} v_n = \sum_{n=a}^{c-1} v_n$.

Comment: Well I have deliver my homework with my attempt that Alfred Mendoza told that was right and thanks for the help :) I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a draft of the proof, you should write it better.

Remember that by Cauchy criteria and given that $\sum{a_n}$ converges, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$|a_n+a_{n-1}+...+a_N|<\varepsilon$$
Then you can choose such $N$ in a way that $n_k>N$ and consequently
$$|b_k+b_{k+1}+...+b_{k+m}|=|a_{n_{k-1}}+...+a_{n_k}+a_{n_k+1}+...+a_{n_{k+1}}+...+a_{n_{k+m-1}+1}+...+a_{n+m}|$$
and that is less than
$$|a_{n_{k+m}}+...+a_N|<\varepsilon$$
That means for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$|b_k+b_{k+1}+...+b_{k+m}|<\varepsilon$$
Consequently by Cauchy criteria, the serie $\sum{b_n}$ converges.
And from the part above it is almost inmediate that $\sum{b_n}$ converges to the same value as $\sum{a_n}$.

Comment: ok thanks, but my attempt is wrong or what happened ?

Comment: There is something wrong, notice that {n_k} is a collection of integers, it doesn't mean that 1,2,... are included in that collection. That means that a_{n_1} is not necessarilly a_1 as you defined in your attempt.

Comment: mmmm I dont agree with that because n_0=0 :)

Comment: then what do yo say about my proof :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I really think that n_0 = 0 doesn't means that n_k = k for every k. However, I don't see where to use that hypothesis. If n_k = k for every k, then for me your proof is exc!

Comment: well no is that n_k=k for every k, is just that the end and the benining in that case, but if you see the other b_k this is not true :), now what you can say :)

Comment: I just reread your proof twice and I just note that I was misunderstanding something with the subscripts :P, so you're right.

Comment: Ok then you are sure that I am absolutely right :) iisnt