# Verify if the following proof is right.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to prove the following:

Suppose $f: [a,b] \to R$ is continous and $g: [c,d] \to [a,b]$ is differentiable. Define $F(x)= \int_{a}^{g(x)}f(t)dt$ for some $x \in [c,d]$. Prove that $F$ is differentiable and compute $F'$.

Before my attempt, we have the following result:

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to R $ is bounded and $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$. Define $F(t)= \int_{a}^{t}f(x)dx$ for $a \le t \le b$. Then:

1) $F$ is continous on $[a,b]$.

2)If $f$ is continous at $x_{0}$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ and $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$

Now my attempt:

We can see $F$ as a composition of two functions:

$g(x)$ and $h(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$

Then, given given that $f$ is continous, by the theorem above $h(x)$ is differentiable , and we know that the composition of two differentiable functions is differentiable, therefore $F$ is differentiable.
To compute the derivative we consider the chain rule:

$F'=(hog)'=(h'(g(x))g'(x)=f(g(x))g'(x)$

**Am I right? or I am missing something, and can you help to fix the wrong things please, thanks for the help.**

Comment: You are wrong. Your argument is incorrect. To see this, consider the counterexample $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: What is $h'(x)$?

Comment: f isnt? this is h'

Comment: Yes, $h'(x) = f(x)$. So what should $F'$ be?

Comment: ok that is rigth :), let me edited, but all the arguments are right isnt?

Comment: I certainly don't like the way you re-define $F$ half-way through, then define $h$ to be exactly the same thing as your new $F$, then revert to your original definition of $F$! If you fix this, it will be correct.

Comment: i dont undestand you?

Comment: "Define $F(x)...$", "Define $F(t)...$".

Comment: I am sorry I still in white with this :)

Comment: so what is what I have to fix? tahnk you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right, you are just applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: ok then everything is good nothing to change :)?

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: ok is because the comments of Tony K :)

Comment: He is wrong with that "counterexample". Notice that if $f(t)=1$, then $f(g(t))=1$ for any function g.

Comment: Then everything is fine with my proof isnt ?

Comment: Can you help me with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020674/series-and-sequences-convergence-with-a-certain-condition plase is important :)

Comment: Yes, everything is fine. I'll try to find an answer for your question.

Comment: Ok I'll apreccieted :) so much :) thank you

Comment: I have edited my question :) Am I rght or what do I have to fix there. Thanks :)